# C macro ## doesn't work for function definition

Tags: c, macros

```
#define FUNCXY(x,y) void FUNC_##x_##y(int){}
#define FUNCXYGOOD(x,y) void FUNCGOOD_##x##_##y(int){}
FUNCXY(2, 1) //get expanded to void FUNC_x_1(int){}
FUNCXYGOOD(2, 1) //get expanded to void FUNCGOOD_2_1(int){}
```

Why doesn't FUNCXY work but FUNCXYGOOD work, that is the C rule behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.  there is no `x_` macro parameter. Underscores are part of the macro token. Underscore is same as any other valid token character

Othersise it would be inposibe to have macro like this:

```
#define FOO(x, xa, xb)
```

Comment: Is ## the standard way to stop the token search?